# RTE should not wrap a <p> tag around an <img> tag

Tags: configuration, config, typo3, typoscript, rte

I work with the RTE and it makes me angry that the RTE does wrap `<p>` tags around an `<img>` tag. What do I have to do that the RTE does not wrap `<p>` tags around the `<img>` tag?

Comment: I know it's possible... I don't have enough time for a proper answer right. Check the lib.parseFunc_RTE configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PageTSConfig something like this

```
RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside = img,hr
```

or

```
RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside := addToList(img)
```

if you want the previous settings and the img additionally